# Consecutive partition by maintain result order in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `MyData` defined as

```
create table MyData (
 id integer not null primary key,
 group_id uuid not null,
 enroll_info text not null,
 enroll_age integer not null default 0,
 enroll_information varchar not null,
 created_stamp date unique not null default now(), 
);
```

And I use the following query where I calculate the rolling minimum:

```
with main_information as (
 select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (partition by (group_id) 
        order by (created_stamp)) as row_num  -- -- -- NOTE_THIS
  from myTable)
select *,
  when count(*) over (partition by group_id rows between current row and following 3) > =3
   then
  minimum(enroll_age) over (partition by (group_id) rows between current row and following 3) 
 else 0 end as rolling_min_value
from main_information;
```

Now the correct output of the `minimum` depends on the rows being sorted on `created_stamp`
, but, as you can see in the above query, I don't have the code:

`minimum(enroll_age) over (partition by (group_id) order by (created_stamp) rows between current row and following 3)`. **Note the order by here**.
**Since**, I don't have this code, I was expecting that rows inside the partition to not be in
order of created_stamp, **But**

I compare my results for the minimum with the expected output and they seem to satisfy tests I've conducted so far, so I saw the output of the columns:
*Sample of 1 partition:*

```
...|created_stamp         |....//other columns including rolling_min_value
_____________________________________
...|2017-03-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-04-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-05-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-06-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-07-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-08-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-09-17 23:43:41   | ...
...|2017-10-17 23:43:41   | ...
```

They seem to be in order. I'm quite confused, if this order is due to the previous partition of the row_num? Or is this mere luck I'm seeing this sorted? BTW, I have 220 rows in the table and all the partitions are sorted in order.

Comment: Yes, it's luck (and probably caused by `row_num`). Do explicitly state the `ORDER`.

Comment: Btw, your `main_information` expression appears to be missing a `FROM` clause and the closing parenthesis

Comment: Yes, your queries are syntactically incorrect. `ROWS BETWEEN` makes no sense if you have no `ORDER BY` in your window definition. I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , I'm just calculating a rolling minimum i.e. min(1,2,3)->row1, min(2,3,4)->row2, min(3,4,5)->row3 etc, but this requires order, the result tests had passed, but, theoritically I believe it should fail I suppose.... , as Bergi mentioned I too believe it's mere luck. But maybe perhaps the optimizer is choosing to cache a partition already created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is interesting to me. The sort order sometimes implicitly affects the query performance and, in your case, the query result.

I was somewhat surprised that the range of rows in the window function can be used without specifying the sort order. However, it is possible.
I don't think it's good to use, but it's possible - and it can bring unexpected results.

When there is no real column to sort, we use a surrogate value in the form of `(select null)` or `(select 1)`. We also do this when we need to number the rows in any way so take a temporary unique row identifier.
In any case, it is desirable to specify the sorting order for its clarity and unambiguity.

Your queries are syntactically incorrect, I have made some changes (CASE, MINimum, > =, ...)
So,

1. First example - your case. Ordering in `CTE`, no order in `over()` clause in main query

```
with main_information as (
 select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by (group_id) 
        order by (created_stamp)) as row_num  -- -- -- NOTE_THIS
  from myData
)
select *,
  case when (count(*) 
     over (partition by group_id rows between current row and 3 following)) >=3
   then
  min(enroll_age) over (partition by (group_id) rows between current row and 3 following) 
 else 0 end as rolling_min_value
from main_information;
```

QUERY PLAN

```
WindowAgg  (cost=51.37..80.17 rows=720 width=96) (actual time=0.140..0.153 rows=5 loops=1)  
  ->  Subquery Scan on main_information  (cost=51.37..65.77 rows=720 width=92) (actual time=0.105..0.116 rows=5 loops=1)  
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=51.37..65.77 rows=720 width=92) (actual time=0.103..0.113 rows=5 loops=1)  
              ->  Sort  (cost=51.37..53.17 rows=720 width=84) (actual time=0.070..0.072 rows=5 loops=1)  
                    Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.created_stamp  
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB  
                    ->  Seq Scan on mydata  (cost=0.00..17.20 rows=720 width=84)(actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=5 loops=1)   

Planning Time: 0.266 ms
Execution Time: 0.826 ms
```

Plan has 1 sorting on Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.created_stamp.
This is sorting from CTE. Data within partition sorted by `created_stamp` ->    Yes, it's luck(c) @Bergi

2. Next example.  No ordering in `CTE`, no order in `over()` clause in main query

```
with main_information as (
 select *
--     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by (group_id) 
--        order by (created_stamp)) as row_num  -- -- -- NOTE_THIS
  from myData
)
select *,
  case when (count(*) 
     over (partition by group_id rows between current row and 3 following)) >=3
   then
  min(enroll_age) over (partition by (group_id) rows between current row and 3 following) 
 else 0 end as rolling_min_value
from main_information;
```

Execution plan

```
WindowAgg  (cost=51.37..67.57 rows=720 width=88) (actual time=0.098..0.108 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=51.37..53.17 rows=720 width=84) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: mydata.group_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on mydata  (cost=0.00..17.20 rows=720 width=84) (actual time=0.024..0.026 rows=5 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.130 ms
Execution Time: 0.145 ms
```

We have 1 sorting with Sort Key: mydata.group_id - this is from `partition by group_id`
Data within partition `not sorted`.
This query my have other result.

3. Next example. Ordering in `CTE` by `Id` and by `created_stamp`.  We don't know, what ordering will turn out to main query.
   No order in `over()` clause in main query.

```
with main_information as (
 select *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by (group_id) 
        order by (id)) as row_by_id  -- -- -- NOTE_THIS
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by (group_id) 
        order by (created_stamp)) as row_by_time  -- -- -- NOTE_THIS
  from myData
)
select *,
  case when (count(*) 
     over (partition by (group_id) rows between current row and 3 following)) >=3
   then
  min(enroll_age) over (partition by (group_id) rows between current row and 3 following) 
 else 0 end as rolling_min_value
from main_information;
```

QUERY PLAN

```
WindowAgg  (cost=51.48..112.42 rows=720 width=104) (actual time=0.212..0.224 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on main_information  (cost=51.48..98.02 rows=720 width=100) (actual time=0.178..0.188 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=51.48..98.02 rows=720 width=100) (actual time=0.176..0.184 rows=5 loops=1)
              ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=51.48..85.42 rows=720 width=92) (actual time=0.173..0.175 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.id
                    Presorted Key: mydata.group_id
                    Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 25kB  Peak Memory: 25kB
                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=51.37..65.77 rows=720 width=92) (actual time=0.111..0.120 rows=5 loops=1)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=51.37..53.17 rows=720 width=84) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=5 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.created_stamp
                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on mydata  (cost=0.00..17.20 rows=720 width=84) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=5 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.297 ms
Execution Time: 0.336 ms
```

We have 2 sorting operation.
First Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.created_stamp
Next  Sort Key: mydata.group_id, mydata.id  Presorted Key: mydata.group_id
Rows in partition sorted by `Id`
Query my have third result.